# How can I bypass the motion sensor on a Handy-Brite solar flood light?

Tags: motion-sensor, solar, bypass

I need to rewire a solar flood light so that when the switch is in the "on" position, the flood light remains on continuously being shut off at the switch. In the "off" position, the flood light would operate as intended, being activated by nearby motion, and turning off in a relatively short period of time afterward. The current wiring is as follows:

Two green wires leading from the on/off switch directly to the motion sensor. Black and red wires connected to the positive/negative battery feeds leading to a push on clip on the circuit board under label "BATT", B+(red) and B-(black). Blue and white wires connected to the solar and soldered on the other ends to the circuit board under label "SUN", S-(white) and S+(blue).

Comment: I don't know the specifics of this unit, but some are designed with relatively undersized batteries, which might mean that a few minutes at a time several times a night will work fine but that if you leave it switched on (not motion detecting) for a couple of hours that the battery will drain, and doing so repeatedly may quickly ruin the battery, depending on how well it is designed.

Comment: Does the Owner's Manual say anything about using the switches to bypass?  I know some hard-wired motion sensor lights can be turned on continuously by double-toggling their switch.

Comment: run a switch from the bms out to the led. The detector might switch + or -, you'll have to determine that, but then you can just "short" between the battery board's respective terminal and the LED module's terminal with a switch, bypassing the motion switching completely without forsaking the battery safety features of the management board (UVP, OCP, etc) by hooking directly from batt to LED.

Comment: alternately, wire a blinking LED and an IR LED in series and aim it at the PIR sensor, and control that tiny trigger LED with a switch.

Comment: Carl Witthoff is correct, the manual will tell you how many features the sensor has and how to adjust the features to fit your need. It's not about wiring unless it does not work at all.